# Android(Galaxy)でホーム画面に一定期間だけ情報を表示し続ける方法

Tags: android, ウィジェット

例えばどうしても忘れてはならない用事があった時、カレンダーアプリにそれを登録していて通知欄には表示されてもスマホを見ればすぐわかる状態にはなりません。
通常のウィジェットだと常に表示され続けるため、特別な用事がある日だけそれを表示し続ける（ホーム画面を操作する時一時的にスワイプなどで消しても、操作が終わったらまた表示する）方法は無いでしょうか？

ピクチャーインピクチャーが一番近いかもしれませんが、ホーム画面を操作する時にサッと消し自動的に再表示は難しそうに思えます。

ウィジェット、ピクチャーインピクチャー、あるいはそれ以外の方法でタイトルの方法を実現するコードを教えてください。

Comment: 当サイトはあくまで「プログラミング」に関する話題を扱う質問サイトです。あなた自身が該当の機能を持つアプリを作ろうとしている上での質問であればよいのですが、単にスマホの使い方、またはアプリを探しているレベルの質問である場合には質問がクローズされる可能性があります。

Comment: コードを教えて欲しい事を明記しました。

Comment: こんな記事 [How to use the Reminder App & set a reminder on your Samsung phone](https://www.samsung.com/uk/support/mobile-devices/how-do-i-use-the-samsung-reminder-app/) で元からリマインダーアプリがあるようですが、それで駄目でもプログラムを作成するまでも無くそうした機能のあるアプリを探してみればよいのでは？ ただしアプリやライブラリを探す質問はこのサイトではオフトピックになりますが。

Comment: @kunif 記事を見ましたが「ホーム画面に（一定期間だけ）情報を表示し続ける方法」は載ってないように見えますが。

Comment: 要望にピッタリというわけではなく、その記事を切っ掛けに、リマインダーの関連で要望に合う機能のあるソフトを探す/有る機能の範囲で工夫する/ソース公開されているものを探して自分で改造する、とかしてみたら良いのではという助言です。リマインダーという名前からして表示し始める時間を調節することは出来るが、いったん表示を始めたら人が何かの操作をするまでは表示し続ける、操作して消しても一定時間後にまた再表示するようにも操作あるいは設定できる、といった機能だと思われますが、貴方のこだわり方からして表示され始めてから一定時間後に自動的に消されなければならないように見える必要性や優先順位はどんなものでしょう？ そういう細かい要望に強くこだわるなら、1個の短い質問に対する簡潔な回答という物は望めないでしょう。それはそれなりの複雑さや規模を持つソフトウェアの開発依頼のようなもので、このサイトとしてはオフトピックになる感じです。

Comment: @kunif  >リマインダーという名前からして（略） 機能だと思われます 実際にそういう機能があるなら記事中に書いてあると思います。また、質問文の中でわかりやすいように例を挙げただけで、実現したいことはリマインダーと関係なくタイトルに書いた通り「ホーム画面に一定期間だけ情報を表示し続ける方法」です。